# Should I delete my backup on my iPhone?

Tags: ios

I want to delete my backup because it’s taking up all my storage but I’m scared too because I don’t want my photos deleted nor my saved games and stuff to be messed up in some way. So if I delete my backup with my games and instagram and Snapchat will it still be the same ??  What happens when you delete your backup ??

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Ask Different. I'd recommend pursuing the following links to learn about Backing Up your iOS device. [About backups for iOS devices](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204136) and [iCloud: Remove an iOS device backup from iCloud](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12792?locale=en_US). Your data currently on your device will not be affected, however if you were wanting to delete the backup you will have no point of restore should your phone suffer damage, and there would be no redundancy post-disaster.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete your backup nothing will happen to your current photos or apps. If in the future though you try and restore from your backup your data will be lost.

To free space if you have a compatible computer you can backup to iTunes which won't use any iCloud space and will only use space on the computer.

To backup to iTunes:

Update to the latest version of iTunes.

> Open iTunes and connect your device to your computer.
>
> If a message asks for your device passcode or to Trust This Computer,
>   follow the onscreen steps. If you forgot your passcode, get help.
>
> Select your iPhone, iPad, or iPod when it appears in iTunes. If your
>   device doesn't appear in iTunes, learn what to do.
>
> If you want to save Health and Activity data from your iOS device or
>   Apple Watch, you need to encrypt your backup: Select the box called
>   Encrypt [device] backup and create a memorable password. If you don't
>   need to save your Health and Activity data, you can make a backup that
>   isn't encrypted. Just click Back Up Now.
>
> When the process ends, you can see if the backup finished successfully
>   on the Summary screen in iTunes. Just look under Latest Backup to find
>   the date and time.

([Source](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT203977#itunes))